# Centering Images With CSS (Without Display: Block)

Tags: css, image, centering

```css
img.imgdemo {
  background: white;
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<a class=imagelink href=periodictable.htm>
  <img class=imgdemo src=ptabledemo.png>
</a>
```

I'm trying to center an image that also acts as a link, but when it has a style of display: block, it acts as a block element, making everything in it's width a link as well. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide code of what you are attempting?

Comment: Just did. When display: block; is set, it does what I just mentioned.

Comment: I think @dwreck08 meant a **working** code. An absolute link to that image, maybe?

Comment: I didn't figure the image particularly mattered. I found an alternate solution of just placing the image and link inside of a div, and then centering the div (which seemed easier), but dwreck's solution worked great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you could use is the `transform: translate()` property and give the `a.imagelink` `display: inline-block`. This will let you set the size of the image to whatever you want and make sure the link is the same size and stays centered at all times:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73ncxpff/1/)

```
a.imagelink {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
img {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Images are inline just like text so:

```
.imagelink {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your image is 200px

```
img {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 200px / 2);
}
```

If your image is 65%

```
img {
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 65% / 2);
}
```